# Radio buttons in Radio group not sized correctly

Tags: android

I have a problem properly sizing radio buttons with background and text in a radio button group.

So basically, I have 10 radio buttons in a grid layout with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:columnCount="10" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_radio_group" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score1" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="1" android:tag="1" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score2" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="2" android:tag="2" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score3" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="3" android:tag="3" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score4" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="4" android:tag="4" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score5" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="5" android:tag="5" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score6" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="6" android:tag="6" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score7" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="7" android:tag="7" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score8" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="8" android:tag="8" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score9" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="9" android:tag="9" android:gravity="center" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score10" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background" android:button="@android:color/transparent" android:checked="false" android:text="10" android:tag="10" android:gravity="center" />
    </RadioGroup>
</GridLayout>
```

The drawable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:left="4sp"
        android:right="4sp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_radio_mobile_01"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:left="4sp"
        android:right="4sp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_radio_mobile_02"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:left="4sp"
        android:right="4sp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_radio_mobile_02"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:left="4sp"
        android:right="4sp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_radio_mobile_01" />
</selector>
```

And the icons (which are circles when displayed outside the layout):

```
<vector android:height="24sp" android:viewportHeight="32"
    android:viewportWidth="32" android:width="24sp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M15.844,15.9m-13.5,0a13.5,13.5 0,1 1,27 0a13.5,13.5 0,1 1,-27 0"
        android:strokeColor="#918D8D" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
</vector>
```

and

```
<vector android:height="24sp" android:viewportHeight="32"
    android:viewportWidth="32" android:width="24sp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M10.83,13.354l4.999,5.834l14.17,-17.501"
        android:strokeColor="#FF5F00" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M29.172,13.775c0.109,0.679 0.162,1.37 0.162,2.078c0,7.456 -6.042,13.499 -13.499,13.499c-7.458,0 -13.501,-6.043 -13.501,-13.499c0,-7.458 6.043,-13.5 13.501,-13.5c1.839,0 3.593,0.366 5.192,1.033"
        android:strokeColor="#FF5F00" android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
</vector>
```

As you can see in the following screen capture, the circles aren't circles anymore...

[image]

Why is that ?

Comment: Try setting the layout_width to match_parent... Additionally, it's recommended to use SP only for text as they can vary based on the font size preference on the device and DP should be used for everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `ConstraintLayout` as the parent instead of `GridLayout`. ConstraintLayout lets you specify an aspect ratio for its children, and you can use this to make sure that your `RadioGroup` is ten times wider than it is tall, which will make each of your ten children be square.

Here's the skeleton of the layout you should use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="10:1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- radio buttons -->

    </RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pretty much all of the important stuff is in the `<RadioGroup>` tag. You use `0dp` for width and height so that the constraints will define both the width and height. The left and right constraints make sure it stretches to fill the screen, and the ratio constraint makes sure you get the right aspect ratio.

You can use nearly the same `RadioButton`s that you have today inside this skeleton. The only change you need to make is to change the height to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/qol_criteria1_score1"
    android:tag="1"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     <---- this needs to change
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:background="@drawable/qol_score_background"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: fantastic answer !

Answer (score 0):

Is this not to do with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`?

Are the radio buttons not trying to stretch out to fill screen width?

Comment: I would say that yes, there are stretching to fill out the screen. This is fine by me, Is there a way to preserve the width/height ratio ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `android:layout_width="0sp"` use `android:layout_width="0dp"`
and change all sp to dp.
 sp is used for text size.

Comment: I agree with the idea behind this answer, but in this case you're using `0` so it won't make a practical difference.